# Why does a forward reference to an img tag fail on Chrome but works on FireFox and IE?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

The following works fine on FireFox and IE, but not on Chrome.  On Chrome, the 'image' id passed to `doSomething()` function is `undefined`, while on FireFox and IE it correctly references the 'img' tag:

```
<div onclick="doSomething(image);"><img id="image" src="test.gif" /></div>
```

Apparently, Chrome can't handle the forward reference?

Comment: It's not really a forward reference in that by the time you actually click the element the img will be in the DOM. I think it's legacy dodgy old-IE behaviour where element ids automatically became global variables, which apparently FF supports but Chrome doesn't. (IE probably should not have supported that behaviour in the first place.) Use `document.getElementById()` as per Mark's answer and you should have no problems.

Comment: @nnnnnn,  your idea is right and I've just learned something new today that surprised me. :-D

Comment: @nnnnnn, as you said `I think it's legacy dodgy old-IE behaviour where element ids automatically became global variables` and it's true because I've tested it in firebug. Can you give me any reference of this where i can read more about this ? Thanks!

Comment: @SheikhHeera - I don't have a particular reference article to hand, but I've seen a few around so I'm sure Google will find you lots of relevant articles and blog posts. I would be surprised if MSDN and MDN don't have articles about it.

Comment: As I posted in the comment to the answer, the simple example I posted seems to work also on Chrome just as long as it's not accompanied by all the rest of the HTML/JS involved in my more complicated scenario.  It's bizarre that whatever is going wrong can kill simple code like that depending upon where it appears on the page!

Comment: Final update: The example works in Chrome only as long as it does not appear in an iframe - that's where Chrome fails to handle it like the other browsers do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly, but I guess your code will work if you use the `getElementById` method:

```
<div onclick="doSomething(document.getElementById('image'));"><img id="image" src="test.gif" /></div>
```

Comment: No need to guess, it _will_ work (unless there's more than one element with that id, though that would be invalid). +1.

Comment: Well, actually, it does NOT work.  But, the problem seems to be something else.  It turns out that my simple example I posted also works on Chrome as a simple test case - just not in the context of my larger pile of HTML/JS (which is actually being generated by the Sandcastle help system).  Although, as I said, everything works fine on both FireFox and IE.  I'll post a follow-up if I can debug the issue...

Comment: FYI, it turns out the getElementById DOES work (if you do it right!) - sorry.  Also, the example fails in Chrome only if it appears anywhere inside an iframe.